# retrieve 2d array from an object and bind to GridView

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, object, multidimensional-array

I have a function that returns a 2 dimensional array.  Due to the nature of the program I MUST declare it as an object. 
Like this

```
object o1 = function(x);    //note the function returns something similar to this {string[x,y]};
```

ultimately I want to bind this data to a GridView.
If the array is **one dimensional**...the following method works fine.

```
gridView.DataSource = o1;

gridView.DataBind();
```

it doesn't work for multidimensional arrays.

I WOULD use the following code to turn the array of strings into a DataTable

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("Name", Type.GetType("System.String"));

dt.Columns.Add("Age", Type.GetType("System.String"));

dt.Columns.Add("Sex", Type.GetType("System.String"));  

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{

    dt.Rows.Add();

    dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["Name"] = o1[i, 0];

    dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["Age"] = o1[i, 1];

    dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["Sex"] = o1[i, 2];

}

GridMultiD.DataSource = dt;

GridMultiD.DataBind();
```

the problem is obviously that the object is not actually an array...but *contains* an array.  Is it possible to access it?  All the Google hits I get are people asking how to make object arrays...

Any ideas to simplify the situation are also greatly appreciated, thanks!

-Dave

note:  the array is
 being returned by a DCOM server... so it MUST be returned as an object...I think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the return type of the function is object but it's actually returning an array of strings, then can you not simply cast the return value?

```
string[,] array = (string[,]) o1;
```

Comment: thank you so much, this solved it!  I didn't realize you could cast something as an array.  :P
(I'm pretty new to this)